# How to set mysql rows to variable in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am new to programming and working on a self-motivated password analyzer project. Part of my program searches User's password through the common password list. Originally I had this folder as .txt file however I wanted to put the list in mySQL server. I was able to connect to my server and create a table with 3 rows that had passwords. However I can't figure out how to tell python to search through the sql server and the rows.
Thank you for the help!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please add the code snippets to your question as well? This might help with copy/paste :)

Comment: I added them. Stackoverflow doesn't let me put the picture so it puts them as links.

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

So, since you're trying to fetch some data from MySQL, you need to initiate the connection with the MySQL server in the first place. Then you can perform your queries on the DB through Python.

##### To initiate connection

- `pip install mysql-connector-python`. [See Install MySQL Connector](https://pynative.com/install-mysql-connector-python/)
- Then you can import the connector in your script `import mysql.connector`.

###### Example

*Updated as per the comments discussion.*

```
from mysql.connector import (connection)

cnx = connection.MySQLConnection(user='scott', password='password',
                                 host='127.0.0.1', # Or 'localhost'
                                 database='employees')
sql_select_query = "select * from passw"
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_select_query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
for record in records:
   password = record[0]

cnx.close()
```

Note: Consider using [environment variables](https://developer.vonage.com/blog/21/10/01/python-environment-variables-a-primer) to securely use sensitive data (MySQL connection data).

---

More details with examples can be found in [Connecting to MySQL Using Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html).

Comment: I was able to connect to the server and even made sure by printing the amount of rows that exist. However I can't figure out how to tell python to find the passwords though the sql table. Thanks for the recommendation to environment variables, ill def look at it

Comment: I just looked at the images you added, if the connection setup is right, you already have what you need. You can iterate over the `records` you fetched and do what you need with them. `for record in records:` ...

Comment: I printed records and it worked. I see the passwords that are saved however its in this format when I print it [(2121,), (21231,), (123456,)] How can I make it where python can search through these and removing the [] and the () so its just the number.

Comment: In Python, `[]` represents a list and `(,)` represents a tuple (You can say it's the immutable version of list). So basically you have a list of tuples. To access your passwords, you can iterate over the list and access the first value in each tuple/record. So, inside `for record in records:` you should do something like: `record[0]` which represents the password itself.